# selenium library - how to expand tree in robotframework

Tags: selenium, robotframework

[when I typed F12-I see this code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F50zm.png)

I want to automate the click on '+':
[expand menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7ujs.png)

whicj commands to use in robot?

Comment: And what you have tried so far? Are you getting any error?

Comment: I tried to click element with Xpath, I tried the id of img, I tried to write the class but nothing worked.
Im sure there is an easy way to do that :)
thanks

Comment: So what happened - it threw an exception there's no such element, or it just didn't expand, or something else? Add the locator(s) you tried with, plus the html _as a text_, screenshots are very bad practice & cause close votes.